# split string column value into multiple rows in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a string column which includes "," delimiter, I want to split this column into multiple rows.

Here's the table

```
|Token          |Shop|
|a              |P   |
|A10,A9a,C1a,F1 |R   |
```

Expected Output:

```
|Token          |Shop|
|a              |P   |
|A10            |R   |
|A9a            |R   |
|C1a            |R   |
|F1             |R   |
```

I tried below logic using mv-expand but it doesn't seem to work

```
datatable(Tokens:string, Shop:string)["a", "P", 
"A10,A9a,C1a,F1", "R" ]
| mv-expand Token =todynamic(Tokens) to typeof(string)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `split()` before `mv-expand`:

```
datatable(Tokens:string, Shop:string)["a","P","A10,A9a,C1a,F1","R" ]
| mv-expand token = split(Tokens, ",") to typeof(string)
```